# Vapor 2 Model to JSON failure

Tags: json, model, vapor

Currently have a class that has two nested vars which are struct types. When I post to the controller I have the JSON validated by mapping the post body to the object using the method below:

```
extension Request {
func user() throws -> User {
    guard let json = json else { throw Abort.badRequest }
    do {
        return try User(json: json)
    } catch  {
        throw Abort.init(.notAcceptable, metadata: nil, reason: "\(json.wrapped)", identifier: nil, possibleCauses: nil, suggestedFixes: nil, documentationLinks: nil, stackOverflowQuestions: nil, gitHubIssues: nil)
    }
}
}
```

Which calls:

```
extension User: JSONInitializable {
  convenience init(json: JSON) throws {
    try self.init(
        type: json.get("type"),
        person: json.get("person")
    )
  }
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting a throw error from the Request.user() method. My Model is solid and I've checked the JSON response against the person object. Person at the moment is:

```
  struct Person {
   var firstName: String
   var lastName: String
   var email: String
   var password: String
   var address: Address 
}

extension Person: JSONInitializable {
 init(json: JSON) throws {
    try self.init(
        firstName: json.get("firstName"),
        lastName: json.get("lastName"),
        email: json.get("email"),
        password: json.get("password"),
        address: json.get("address")
    )
  }
}
```

It's very basic so it should pass the mapped validation. Does this struct also need to conform to `Vapor Model subclass` for it to map correctly or is there something else wrong?

edit: Added User

```
final class User: Model {

let storage = Storage()
var type: String
var person: Person

init(type: String, person: Person) {
    self.type   = type
    self.person = person
}

//MARK: Parse row from the database
init(row: Row) throws {
    type = try row.get("type")
    person = try row.get("person")
}

//MARK: Adding a row to the database
func makeRow() throws -> Row {
    var row = Row()
    try row.set("person", person)
    try row.set("type", type)
    try row.set("country", person.address.country)
    return row
}

}

extension User: JSONInitializable {

// MARK: Will be the request in json format
convenience init(json: JSON) throws {
    try self.init(
        type: json.get("type"),
        person: json.get("person")

    )
}
}

extension User: Timestampable, SoftDeletable, JSONConvertible {

//MARK: Convert user to json to pass back
func makeJSON() throws -> JSON {
    var json = JSON()
    try json.set("id", id)
    try json.set("type", type)
    try json.set("person", person)
    return json
}

}

// Fluent DB Preparation
extension User: Preparation {

static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
    try database.create(self) { builder in
        builder.id()
        builder.string("person")
        builder.string("type")
        builder.string("country")
    }
}

static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
    try database.delete(self)
}
}

extension User: ResponseRepresentable, NodeRepresentable {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Person` struct also needs to conform to `JSONInitializable`. Your `User` extension is trying to create a `Person` from JSON but doesn't know how. What's more, you'll also need to conform `Address` as this appears to be a custom type as well.

As an alternative, with Swift 4 you can also use the [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) protocols to create your models from JSON.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the suggested structure (which makes sense) however the issue still persists.

Comment: `"identifier": "Vapor.Abort.notAcceptable"` - Which is the extension error above.

Comment: And what if you remove your `catch` statement and just let Swift report the actual error thrown by `try User(json: json)`?

Comment: Something about `Node.fuzzyConverters` and `"debugReason": "No converters found for type ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Person>",`

Comment: I removed the ! associated with person and now the build error is: `Struct 'self.person' must be completely initialized before a member is stored to`

Comment: These messages are telling you that you haven't correctly created a `Person` from the JSON. Can you update the question with your full code? What you are trying to do is entirely possible. We just need to see how you are doing it to discover where you have missed a step.

Comment: Updated my question: The address struct is the same structure as person.

Comment: On your `Person` (and probably `Address`) structs, implement `init(json: JSON)` as an actual initialiser, rather than delegating to `self.init`. Set your properties directly there: `firstName = try json.get("firstName")` etc.

Comment: Almost there: `NOT NULL constraint failed users.address`

Comment: Got it working: Conforming structs to `JSONRepresentable` solved it. Thanks for your help.